# Partitioning that gives the same rank if the next row status is the same

Tags: sql, postgresql, grouping, partitioning, ranking

Looking for help solving a partitioning issue where I'm trying to give the same rank if the next row has the same status as the previous. The dataset is similar to this:

```
 log_id    user    status    date
 1         1       a         2020-01-01
 2         1       b         2020-01-03
 3         1       a         2020-01-18
 4         1       a         2020-02-03
 5         1       c         2020-02-05
 6         2       a         2020-01-05
 7         2       c         2020-01-10
 8         2       b         2020-01-12
 9         2       a         2020-01-21
10         2       a         2020-01-23
11         2       a         2020-01-28
12         2       b         2020-01-29
```

I've tried partitioning the rows by user through this:

```
select
t.*,
rank() over (partition by t.user order by t.date) as rank_order
from table t
```

This will get me the the simple rank of log id's by user:

```
 log_id    user    status    date         rank_order
 1         1       a         2020-01-01   1
 2         1       b         2020-01-03   2
 3         1       a         2020-01-18   3
 4         1       a         2020-02-03   4
 5         1       c         2020-02-05   5
 6         2       a         2020-01-05   1
 7         2       c         2020-01-10   2
 8         2       b         2020-01-12   3
 9         2       a         2020-01-21   4
10         2       a         2020-01-23   5
11         2       a         2020-01-28   6
12         2       b         2020-01-29   7
```

But I'd like to give the same rank if the next row has the same status. Which would be something like this:

```
 log_id    user    status    date         desired_rank_order
 1         1       a         2020-01-01   1
 2         1       b         2020-01-03   2
 3         1       a         2020-01-18   3
 4         1       a         2020-02-03   3
 5         1       c         2020-02-05   4
 6         2       a         2020-01-05   1
 7         2       c         2020-01-10   2
 8         2       b         2020-01-12   3
 9         2       a         2020-01-21   4
10         2       a         2020-01-23   4
11         2       a         2020-01-28   4
12         2       b         2020-01-29   5
```

Comment: It looks like you want `dense_rank` instead of `rank`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
select *,
  sum(inc) over(partition by user order by date) as rank_order
from (
  select *,
    case when lag(status) over(partition by user order by date) = status
      then 0 else 1 end as inc   
  from t
) x
```